# Calculo de cubagem com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso calcular a largura * altura * comprimento * quantidade.

O Script esta calculando apenas dos campos que inicial, os que são adicionados de acordo com a necessidade não são incluídos no calculo.

O primeiro calculo é de cada linha:

```
#cubagemMateriais = (.comprimentoMaterial * .larguraMaterial * .alturaMaterial) * .volumeMaterial
```

Soma todos os recultados #cubagemMateriais e exibe no:

```
#cubagemMateriaisTotal
```

## Testes

- Usando a opção de clone: http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/5/
- Duplicando o formulário funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/4/

Parece que o cloque não funciona.

Meu código:

```
<div id="formularioMateriais">
    <div class="row">
            Volume.........: <input name="volumeMaterial[]" id="" type="number" class="form-control volumeMaterial" value="" required><br>
            Material.........:<input name="nomeMaterial[]"  id="" type="text" class="form-control nomeMaterial" value="" required><br>
            Compimento..:<input name="comprimentoMaterial[]"  id="" type="text" class="form-control comprimentoMaterial" value="" required><br>
            Largura..........:<input name="larguraMaterial[]" id="" type="text" class="form-control larguraMaterial" value="" required><br>
            Altura.............:<input name="alturaMaterial[]"  id="" type="text" class="form-control alturaMaterial" value="" required>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs adicionarCampo2" data-id="2" id="" style="margin:35px 0 0 0"><i class="fa fa-plus bigger-110 icon-only"></i>+ </a><br>

            <b>Soma da linha</b>.:<input name="cubagemMateriais[]" id="cubagemMateriais" type="text" >
            <hr>
    </div>
</div>
Soma total <input  id="cubagemMateriaisTotal" >
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var divContent2 = $('#formularioMateriais');
    var botaoAdicionar2 = $('a[data-id="2"]');
    var i2 = 1;

    //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
    $(botaoAdicionar2).click(function () {
        $('<div class="conteudoIndividual2"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-1"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Volume</label><input name="volumeMaterial[]" type="number" class="form-control volumeMaterial" id="" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-4"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Material</label><input name="nomeMaterial[]" type="text" class="form-control nomeMaterial" id="" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Compimento</label><input name="comprimentoMaterial[]" type="text" class="form-control comprimentoMaterial" id="" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Largura</label><input name="larguraMaterial[]" type="text" class="form-control larguraMaterial" id="" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Altura</label><input name="alturaMaterial[]" type="text" class="form-control alturaMaterial" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-1"><div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs linkRemover2" style="margin:35px 0 0 0"><i class="fa fa-times bigger-110 icon-only"></i></button></div><input name="cubagemMateriais[]" id="cubagemMateriais" ></div></div></div>').appendTo(divContent2);
        $('#removehidden2').remove();
        i2++;
        $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos2" value="' + i2 + '" id="removehidden2">').appendTo(divContent2);
    });

    //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
    $('#formularioMateriais').on('click', '.linkRemover2', function () {
        $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual2').remove();
        i2--;
    });
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".alturaMaterial, .comprimentoMaterial, .larguraMaterial, .volumeMaterial").on('keyup', function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
        var cubagemMateriais = [".volumeMaterial", ".comprimentoMaterial", ".larguraMaterial", ".alturaMaterial"].reduce(function (soma, classe) {
            var value = parseInt($row.find(classe).val(), 10);
            return value * soma;
        }, 1);
        $row.find('input[name="cubagemMateriais[]"]').val(cubagemMateriais || 0);

        // somar todas as linhas
        var total = $('input[name="cubagemMateriais[]"]').get().reduce(function (soma, input) {
            var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
            return value + soma;
        }, 0);
        $('#cubagemMateriaisTotal').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: Existe algum HTML separador/wrapper de cada linha? Porquê `mouseover`?

Comment: Essa é uma versão mais simplificada. `mouseover` é somente para teste.

Comment: A resposta fica bem mais simples se houver um separador entre linhas no HTML. Existe? tipo uma `div` que contem cada linha?

Comment: @Sergio separei a parte do form veja nesse link http://jsfiddle.net/y0x18e2p/ visualmente fica assim http://i.imgur.com/Q8JRvdH.png

Comment: @Sergio Correção http://jsfiddle.net/y0x18e2p/1/

Comment: Por favor, especifique no texto da pergunta qual o ser problema exato.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Acho que o problema é do clone. Eu dupliquei manualmente e funciona, veja http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/4, mas quando uso o form do clone não funciona http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/3/

Comment: Como resolver essa questão de suspensão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É importante achares uma maneira de fazer isso que seja escalável. Ou seja: tenha o mesmo código independentemente do numero de linhas. Isso implica depender menos de ID's que são por natureza únicas. Sugestão de código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formularioMateriais').on('keyup', 'input', function (e) {
        var $row = $(e.target).closest('.row');
        var cubagemMateriais = [".volumeMaterial", ".comprimentoMaterial", ".larguraMaterial", ".alturaMaterial"].reduce(function (soma, classe) {
            var value = parseInt($row.find(classe).val(), 10);
            return value * soma;
        }, 1);
        $row.find('input[name="cubagemMateriais[]"]').val(cubagemMateriais || 0);

        // somar todas as linhas
        var total = $('input[name="cubagemMateriais[]"]').get().reduce(function (soma, input) {
            var value = parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0;
            return value + soma;
        }, 0);
        $('#cubagemMateriaisTotal').val(total);
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/6/

O `.reduce()` é muito util aqui para somar valores de uma array.

Comment: Aqui não esta calculando, fica sempre 0

Comment: @Tiago repara que estou a usar classes. Então tive de adicionar classe `volumeMaterial` no primeiro input, e também mudei de ID para class no input total de cada linha.

Comment: ele esta calculado somente uma linha, veja http://i.imgur.com/uXSRjGT.png

Comment: Coloquei os dois codigo juntos. O de add nova linha e o seu de calculo. No meu arquivo o add nova linha funciona, mas nesse link não, mas da para você ver como é. veja http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/1/

Comment: Atualizado http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/3/

Comment: Acho que o problema é do clone. Eu dupliquei manualmente e funciona, veja http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/4/

Comment: @Tiago: este funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/6/, usando delegação como sugerí na resposta.

Comment: bom dia.Seu código funcionou, mas tem um detalhe. Ex, adiciono linhas a soma fica certinha! Mas quando excluo alguma linha não faz o recalculo.

Comment: @Tiago http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/7/

Comment: Funcionou :), mas encontrei outro falha...rsrs, como os valores colocados ali são em metros para descobrir o peso cubico, não aparece o resultado certo. **Ex: 1.50 x 1.50 x 1.50 = 3.375** no resultado esta aparecendo 1

Comment: @Tiago usa `parseFloat` em vez de `parseInt` -> http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/8/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23768/discussion-between-sergio-and-tiago).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! isso que vou perguntar é somete um detalhe. Usando o exemplo **Ex: 1.50 x 1.50 x 1.50 = 3.375** aparece o valor correto de três dígitos após o ponto no peso. Mas se eu dobro por exemplo, o resultado é **6.75** quando é zero no final não aparece. É fazer com que apareça?

Comment: esqueci de um detalhe. No calculo da cubagem **((Largura * Altura * Comprimento) * Quantidade)** precisa ser multiplicado por 300, ficando assim. **(((Largura * Altura * Comprimento) * Quantidade) * 300)**. Onde eu acrescento os 300 para ser multiplicado?

Comment: @Tiago na linha 29 deste fiddle muda `1` para `300`: http://jsfiddle.net/xp3v2grg/8/

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente.