# Mascara para peso

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pesquisando na internet, achei um código que faz mascara de peso no campo. Mas esse código funciona com critério do ID.

Gostaria que funcionasse com CLASS, para poder usar em outros campos.

```
function id(el){
        return document.getElementById(el);
}
window.onload = function(){
        id('peso').onkeyup = function(){
            var v = this.value,
                integer = v.split('.')[0];


            v = v.replace(/\D/, "");
            v = v.replace(/^[0]+/, "");

            if(v.length <= 3 || !integer)
            {
                if(v.length === 1) v = '0.00' + v;
                if(v.length === 2) v = '0.0' + v;
                if(v.length === 3) v = '0.' + v;
            } else {
                v = v.replace(/^(\d{1,})(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2");
            }

            this.value = v;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que o teu problema inclua campos genaros dinamicamente, e daí precises usar delegação. A minha sugestão é:

```
function mascara() {
    var v = this.value, integer = v.split('.')[0];
    v = v.replace(/\D/, "");
    v = v.replace(/^[0]+/, "");

    if (v.length <= 3 || !integer) {
        if (v.length === 1) v = '0.00' + v;
        if (v.length === 2) v = '0.0' + v;
        if (v.length === 3) v = '0.' + v;
    } else {
        v = v.replace(/^(\d{1,})(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2");
    }

    this.value = v;
}
$('#elementoPai').on('keyup', '.peso', mascara);
```

Se juntares mais informação de como queres formatar a saída podemos ajudar a adaptar a máscara.

Answer (score 1):

No lugar de

```
function id(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
```

}

Coloque

```
function id(el){
   return document.getElementsByClassName(el);
}
```

E coloca uma class com o nome 'peso' no seu elemento.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` dá uma lista/array. Assim como está vai dar erro... tens de ter pelo menos [0], ou seja `return document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar diretamente o jQuery para isso, caso não esteja usando campos gerados dinamicamente:

```
$('.peso').keyup(function () {
    var v = this.value,
        integer = v.split('.')[0];

    v = v.replace(/\D/, "");
    v = v.replace(/^[0]+/, "");

    if (v.length <= 3 || !integer) {
        if (v.length === 1) v = '0.00' + v;
        if (v.length === 2) v = '0.0' + v;
        if (v.length === 3) v = '0.' + v;
    } else {
        v = v.replace(/^(\d{1,})(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2");
    }

    this.value = v;
});
```

Também sugiro mudar a linha

```
v = v.replace(/\D/, "");
```

para

```
v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

Para remover corretamente as letras.

Comment: Esse post foi bloqueado por você, mas ele já foi resolvido e atualizei para melhor visualização, mas ainda continua bloqueado, como solucionar? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63821/calculo-de-cubagem-com-jquery/63831

Comment: Eu não bloqueei o post, não tenho permissão para isso. Eu apenas votei, junto com outros usuários, para manter fechada a questão, pois na hora que entrei na fila de avaliação não tinha reposta aceita, o texto da pergunta não estava claro e reparei que você abriu outra pergunta para o mesmo tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63849/calcular-valores-de-v%C3%A1rios-campos . Se quiser reabrir a pergunta, edite-a que ela cairá na fila de revisão para reabertura.

Comment: Já foi alterada, não e a original mais.